# How to reduce memory consumption in MingW based GUI Application

Tags: memory

I just noticed the memory usage ( using task manager) by the simple GUI application ( with single main window ) is around 3 MB .

I used Dev-c++ and Mingw as compiler

Is there anyway to reduce this ?

Comment: What libraries are you using, what framework, what language?

Comment: Seems to me like you better ask this on stackoverflow.com. I also fail to see how 3 MB is in any way too much.

Comment: @EFraim , dev-c++ ide , mingw win32 C application

Comment: Now also on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373456/how-to-reduce-memory-consumption-in-mingw-based-gui-application

Comment: is this more than it would be if you compiled, with, say visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this method in Main method yields a better result in task manager :)

```
SetProcessWorkingSetSize(GetCurrentProcess(), (SIZE_T) -1, (SIZE_T) -1);
```